# Javascript - Remove element from javascript <String,String> map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have the following Javascript object

```
[  
   "{\"id\":\"b00a3a47-783a-4af5-90d9-59c4deb7a9e3\",\"notes\":\"sdfsdf\",\"recordType\":0}",
   "{\"id\":\"a6f72972-502e-452b-9773-51699a527122\",\"notes\":\"sdfsfdf\",\"recordType\":0}"
]
```

how do I remove the element where ID = "a6f72972-502e-452b-9773-51699a527122"?
(doesnt have to literally be "a6f72972-502e-452b-9773-51699a527122", thats just an example.

I have tried the following

```
var index = detailsArray.map(function (element) {
                    console.log("element = " + JSON.stringify(element) + " index = " + index + " id = " + element.id);
                    return element.id;
                }).indexOf(detailId);
                console.log("index of " + detailId + " = " + index);
                delete detailsArray[index];
```

But it is returning element.id as undefined. I suspect its because the 'property' of the element is a String, i'm unsure how to solve this.

Comment: Is there a reason you have an array of strings that look like an object instead of an array of actual objects?

Comment: Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). **Code:** `var newArr = arr.filter(function(e) { return JSON.parse(e).id !== uglyId; });`

Comment: @NickZ Yes, the array is actually from a Java Map<String,String> and it is getting stored this way on my backend.

Comment: @Tushar I have attempted that before, but my issue is element.id is returning 'undefined'. Thanks for your comment though Edit: I will try your edited comment, thanks.

Comment: @Tushar Sorry man, i read the old one that didnt have the JSON.parse(e) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to parse those strings as JSON. In the interest of providing a solution that actually mutates the `detailsArray` by removing the offending index (as opposed to creating a copy without it), here's a sort of `indexOf` via callback using `Array.prototype.reduce`

```
var index = detailsArray.reduce(function(prev, curr, idx) {
    return prev === -1 && JSON.parse(curr).id === detailId ?
        idx : prev;
}, -1);
if (index > -1) {
    detailsArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

```js
var detailsArray = [
      "{\"id\":\"b00a3a47-783a-4af5-90d9-59c4deb7a9e3\",\"notes\":\"sdfsdf\",\"recordType\":0}",
      "{\"id\":\"a6f72972-502e-452b-9773-51699a527122\",\"notes\":\"sdfsfdf\",\"recordType\":0}"
   ],
   detailId = 'a6f72972-502e-452b-9773-51699a527122';
    
var index = detailsArray.reduce(function(prev, curr, idx) {
  return prev === -1 && JSON.parse(curr).id === detailId ?
    idx : prev;
}, -1);
if (index > -1) {
    detailsArray.splice(index, 1);
}

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(detailsArray, null, '  ');
```

```html
<pre id="out">detailsArray = </pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Phil, it is working! One question though since you mentioned the mutate part.. Is there a way to use the JSON.parse without mutating the original array?

Comment: @hitch.united by *"mutate"* I mean that `detailsArray` is itself modified by removing the desired index as opposed to creating a copy without the found index as seen in the other answers using `filter()`

Comment: Ok I understand, Im running into an issue now when I use JSON.parse(element). It looks like it's actually changing the object in my detailsArray to JSON now, so when it gets saved its breaking my map in java.

Comment: @hitch.united you must be altering it somewhere else then. Neither this code nor the code in the other answer changes the array values

Comment: You were right, i was changing it somewhere else. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It is just an array of JSON strings.
If you want to filter them, then simply parse every item and check `id` for equality:

```
var arr = [  
   "{\"id\":\"b00a3a47-783a-4af5-90d9-59c4deb7a9e3\",\"notes\":\"sdfsdf\",\"recordType\":0}",
   "{\"id\":\"a6f72972-502e-452b-9773-51699a527122\",\"notes\":\"sdfsfdf\",\"recordType\":0}"
];

var result = arr.filter(function(x) {
  return JSON.parse(x).id !== 'a6f72972-502e-452b-9773-51699a527122';
});
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/3kkerqz3/1/).